# Sphere packing with target volume fraction

Tags: random, computational-geometry, packing

I've stumbled [upon this sphere packing question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11940/randomly-packing-spheres-of-fixed-radius-within-a-cube/11998#11998), and now I have another related one.

How can I have a function that returns a sphere packing *with a target volume fraction*? Sphere can obviously have different radii.

Thanks for your hints!

Comment: I suspect this is a special case of the NP-complete knapsack problem and hence no polynomial algorithm exists.

Comment: Yes, it is, but I am also content with some brute-force approximated solutions.

Comment: This sounds like it could be an interesting puzzle, but I think I might be missing the point. Can you be a bit more specific? What are the constraints on the (radius distribution of/number of/placement of/etc.) spheres? Why not just stop the linked function when the right volume is reached? Why would returning a single sphere of the target volume be wrong (aside from being boring)?

Comment: The most probable constraint is passing a probability distribution to the computation, so that radii will adhere (more or less) to it. Yes, I'd like to stop when the target volume ratio is obtained, but a single sphere would be so boring, I agree with you!